# Why it's useful to create RVM gemset for rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails

It's recommended to create a separate RVM gemset for each rails project.
But I don't understand, why it's useful. Are there only aesthetics reasons?
Because it is possible to install multiple gem versions globally and then write a version in Gemfile in case I need a specific version of a gem.

Comment: Don't use gemsets. They were created in a time before Bundler was widely used.

Answer (score 0):

May be if you are using command 'gem install ...' and don't want the gem to be installed globally, rvm gemset is a good idea. I don't see any other reasons.

Comment: also you may want to create a gemset per project https://coderwall.com/p/bvkgtw/easy-way-to-create-gemset-per-project-using-rvm